# OpenShot will not upgrade

Tags: command-line, upgrade, software-installation

I just installed openshot video editor via terminal: this tutorial https://www.ubuntupit.com/install-openshot-video-editor-ubuntu-linux-mint/ on ubuntu 21.04 on a raspberry pi 4b. I tried to start it, but it showed this glitch warning and openshot did not start.

[image]

Here's something that N0rbert wanted me to do in terminal (I didn't get that at first) but here it is. At the bottom of this, there is an additional terminal entry NOrbert wanted me to add so I did it too.

```
pi@pi-raspberrypi:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for pi: 
root@pi-raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt-cache policy openshot
openshot:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.5.1+dfsg1-1
  Version table:
     2.5.1+dfsg1-1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
root@pi-raspberrypi:/home/pi# snap list | grep -i openshot
root@pi-raspberrypi:/home/pi#  flatpak list | grep -i openshot
Command 'flatpak' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install flatpak
root@pi-raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt install flatpak
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libappstream-glib8 libmalcontent-0-0 libostree-1-1
Suggested packages:
  malcontent-gui
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  flatpak libappstream-glib8 libmalcontent-0-0 libostree-1-1
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,460 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,902 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute/universe arm64 libappstream-glib8 arm64 0.7.18-1 [129 kB]
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute/universe arm64 libmalcontent-0-0 arm64 0.10.0-2 [19.8 kB]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute/universe arm64 libostree-1-1 arm64 2020.8-2 [266 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute/universe arm64 flatpak arm64 1.10.2-1ubuntu1 [1,045 kB]
Fetched 1,460 kB in 1s (1,516 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libappstream-glib8:arm64.
(Reading database ... 276399 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libappstream-glib8_0.7.18-1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libappstream-glib8:arm64 (0.7.18-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmalcontent-0-0:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../libmalcontent-0-0_0.10.0-2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libmalcontent-0-0:arm64 (0.10.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libostree-1-1:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../libostree-1-1_2020.8-2_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libostree-1-1:arm64 (2020.8-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package flatpak.
Preparing to unpack .../flatpak_1.10.2-1ubuntu1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking flatpak (1.10.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libappstream-glib8:arm64 (0.7.18-1) ...
Setting up libostree-1-1:arm64 (2020.8-2) ...
Setting up libmalcontent-0-0:arm64 (0.10.0-2) ...
Setting up flatpak (1.10.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-0ubuntu5) ...
root@pi-raspberrypi:/home/pi# snap list | grep -i openshot
root@pi-raspberrypi:/home/pi# which openshot
root@pi-raspberrypi:/home/pi# 

pi@pi-raspberrypi:~$ apt-cache  policy openshot-qt libopenshot
openshot-qt:
  Installed: 2.6.0+dfsg2+1454+202108251849~ubuntu21.04.1
  Candidate: 2.6.0+dfsg2+1454+202108251849~ubuntu21.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.6.0+dfsg2+1454+202108251849~ubuntu21.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.5.1+dfsg1-1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
libopenshot:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
pi@pi-raspberrypi:~$
```

I did these entries one after another plus a couple more in one terminal session. THese were suggested in a comment to this question by NOrbert so I did them here.
I tried running `apt-update` and `full-upgrade` in terminal but it did not upgrade. How would I install the latest installer?  How can I fix this?

Comment: Details needed. Please add output of `apt-cache policy openshot`; `snap list | grep -i openshot` ; `flatpak list | grep -i openshot` ; `which openshot` to the question.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Essential information as this issue will be specific to your Ubuntu version. Also add to your question (use "Edit") how you installed the software (using Snap Store, or is it installed through a third party PPA or downloaded file?)

Comment: I will try to clarify both of these questions here. NOrbert first. I do not know what the first four things are (please explain), but I have openshot 0.2.5 installed; I need 0.2.6. vanadium's question. I am using ubuntu 21.04 on raspberry pi 4b. I installed it with this tutorial https://www.ubuntupit.com/install-openshot-video-editor-ubuntu-linux-mint/. in short, I did it via terminal,

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1370308/edit) and add your clarifications in the questions. As for @N0rbert 's request, open a terminal (the app called Terminal) and type the commands one at a time followed by the "Enter" key. Copy and paste the output of the command in your question. Repeat for all the commands. Note, each command is separated in the above comment by a ";".

Comment: How OpenShot was really installed? Please add more details.

Comment: I just did what the tutorial said. That's all I know about it.

Comment: Ok, then please add output of `apt-cache  policy openshot-qt libopenshot*` to the question.

Comment: Ok NOrbert, I added that too.  If there is anything else that you want me to add just let me know and I'll do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["OpenShot: Stable PPA - Official Releases" PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eopenshot.developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) does not contain `libopenshot` libraries for *armhf* and/or *arm64*. They support [only *amd64*](https://launchpad.net/%7Eopenshot.developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=hirsute) (for Intel/AMD computers, not Raspberry Pi).
I have wrote a request about building packages for Raspberry Pi.

Currently you have to remove OpenShot PPA with commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
```

and then you will have older but fully-functional OpenShot from official repository.

Comment: I tried to build from the same source for ARM, but it is failing to build. https://launchpad.net/~apandada1/+archive/ubuntu/expt/+build/22588181

Comment: It complains about missed FindOpenShotAudio.cmake , so libopenshot-audio-dev should be built before OpenShot, probably.

Answer (score 1):

You can download an appimage from the openshot website here: https://www.openshot.org/en/download/

Since it's an appimage, no installation is required. As of this writing, the version offered is 2.6.1

From this page, you can download the single file `OpenShot-v2.6.1-x86_64.Appimage`. Once downloaded, it needs to be marked as executable, either by setting the properties in your file manager of choice, or by `chmod +x OpenShot-v2.6.1-x86_64.Appimage` in a terminal.

Then you run it by double-clicking it in the file manager, or typing `./OpenShot-v2.6.1-x86_64.Appimage` in the terminal.

Final edit: according to the OP, the appimage did not work on his computer, although it did work on mine.

Comment: That didn't really work; when I ran the launch binary called AppRun, It said there is no app installed to run the "shared binary" files.  Is there an app I can install for that?

Comment: @2-bituser For detailed help on installation problems, your best bet is probably to contact the developers of the application. They give an "ask a question" link here: https://www.reddit.com/r/OpenShot/

Comment: @2-bituser I just downloaded it and it worked fine on my pc. All I had to do was mark it executable. Maybe there is an issue running it on a pi. Here's a screenshot https://imgur.com/zebcZfe I'm not sure what you mean by the  "launch binary" either, I just got a single file downloaded called OpenShot-v2.6.1-x86_64.Appimage

Comment: That's mighty wierd. It looks sort of like a zip file on mine. When I double click on it, it opens like a zip yet it says .appimage in the title.

Comment: @2-bituser yes, either that or use the properties setting in the file manager to do it. I think it's `chmod +x (filename)` though. See updated answer.

Comment: I just gave it a go and nothing seems to have happened. Here's the terminal output pi@pi-raspberrypi:~/Downloads$ chmod +x OpenShot-v2.6.1-x86_64.AppImage
pi@pi-raspberrypi:~/Downloads$

Comment: @2-bituser try it in a terminal and see if you get any error messages. When I ran it in a terminal it produced a bunch of "informational messages". I'm not sure what the last part of your comment means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130676/discussion-between-2-bituser-and-bill-miller).

Comment: x86_64 will not work on arm64, but nice try.